# trouble with lisp macro around and

Tags: macros, common-lisp

So I wanted to write an all macro that takes a list of elements and returns if they are all non-falsey.  I thought to do it as a macro like

```
(defmacro all (ls) 
  `(and ,@ls))
```

That works when I test with

```
(all (1 2 3))
```

but not

```
(all '(1 2 3))
```

or any other list.  I am not really sure why.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. What is the meaning of ', quote**

`'s-expression` is just a syntactic abbreviation for `(QUOTE s-expression)`, so `'(1 2 3)` is an abbreviation for the two-element list `(QUOTE (1 2 3))`

**2. How a macro is evaluated**

A macro is function that transforms a form (an s-expression) in another, and it is normally used to add new syntactic constructs to the language.

For this reason the arguments of a macro are not evaluated. They are taken literally and bound to the macro parameters.

So the macro `all`, when used, bounds the list argument to the `ls` parameter without any evaluation, and transforms the list into a new list inserting the atom `and` as first element:

```
(all (1 2 3))  =>  (AND 1 2 3)
```

the resulting form is then interpreted or compiled for subsequent evaluation.

If you write `(all '(1 2 3)` this is equivalent to `(all (QUOTE (1 2 3))` and the transformation is the following:

```
(all '(1 2 3)) => (all (QUOTE (1 2 3)) => (AND QUOTE (1 2 3))
```

which is problably different from what you are expecting and wich produces several errors (variable `QUOTE` not bound, car of `(1 2 3)` is not a function name or lambda-expression).

**3. Debugging a macro**

If you want to see how a macro is expanded, you can use the `macroexpand-1` primitive function (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mexp_.htm#macroexpand-1)):

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(all (1 2 3)))
(AND 1 2 3)

CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(all '(1 2 3)))
(AND QUOTE (1 2 3))
```

Comment: I thought that ,@x is supposed to evaluate x and splice in the value though. So I am not getting how I am suppose to pass an actual list to this macro that will be pasted into the and expression as desired.

Comment: ,@x takes the s-expression associated to x (which is (1 2 3)), and splice the list. But what is passed to the macro is **never** evaluated. You **cannot** pass a run-time value to a macro. For instance, if you do `(let ((x '(1 2 3))) (all x))` you obtain the error: "The value X is not of the expected type LIST.". This is because the s-expression associated to `ls` is the symbol `X`, not its value.

Comment: A macro cannot be used to compute a value at run-time, for that one should use a function.

Comment: I really don't get it.  Is the claim that it is impossible to unroll a list inside a macro?  I don't believe that can be so. I believe there must be a way to do this correctly.  In the case of the surrounding let the list was already evaluated before the macro was even called. I also tried a let when the macro which still did not work.

Comment: You should distinguish between a literal list, like (1 2 3), and something that evaluate to a list (for instance a variable). Your **macro** accepts a literal list, while a generic **function** could accept any expression that evaluate to a list. So your macro can be only called with the literal list that has to be modified, not with any expression that is evaluated to a list, like a variable, a function or macro call, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So this works.

```
(defmacro all (ls)
 `(reduce (lambda (a b) (and a b)) ,ls))
```

Although it isn't as concise or pleasing to me.